# Trying to get Jade to redirect page

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
FB.setAccessToken(req.body.accessToken);
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        Promise.try(function() {
                return routes.getUser(response);
        }).then(function(newResponse) { 
                res.render('groups', newResponse);
        }).catch(function(e) {
                console.error(e);
        });
});
```

Client-Side:

```
function checkToken(response){
    $.post('/auth', {
            id: response.authResponse.userID,
            accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken
    });
}
```

Once it reaches the end of the Promise chain in the code above, It should redirect the client to a new view, `groups`. I'm not getting any errors  when running the application. How can I get Jade to send the client a new view?

Is it possible to render a new view that replaces the current view? Or will I have to redirect the page (on the client-side) for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jade is a template engine and doesn't actually have anything to do with your question.  Express handles the routes, which is what you use to define what gets loaded where and when it gets loaded.

Making an AJAX call with `$.post` won't reload your page (that's the primary purpose of making an AJAX call).  Based on your current code, you'll need to add a callback to your `$.post` call and once you receive the data, replace the current page's HTML with the HTML from the AJAX call.  You could also do something like `window.location.href = 'new page URL here';`.

Last but not least, you could do `res.redirect` on the server, but it would NOT be in the current code shown.  Whatever route you have that loads the page with that bit of JavaScript needs to instead run the same server-side logic, and then do `res.redirect` or just directly load the correct template with `res.render` at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with Jade, as noted in the michael's answer.

> Is it possible to render a new view that replaces the current view?

No. Rendering (in this case) happens at server-side. Once the rendered HTML has been sent to the client and the browser has displayed* it, server can no longer affect the page directly.

<sup>(*also called rendering but this is related to the browser actually painting the page for the client, [more details](http://google.com/search?q=browser+rendering))</sup>

Once you do a `res.render` (or `res.send`, `res.redirect`) in a route handler it will be the last thing you can do from the server to affect the page, or more generally, the response sent to the client, which in `res.redirect` will just be a 302 status code and a location header. (sending the response twice in the same handler may cause "headers already sent" errors)

It's all upto client to change the view then, so...

> Or will I have to redirect the page (on the client-side) for this?

exactly.